# Taking data of an editable table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, firebase, dom-events

I made an HTML Editable table with the property CONTENTEDITABLE, each TD has an ID (long way but I need it for today and I know only JS basics) to know what info has inside, it is wrapped by a form. At the end I have a button that if I press it will show on console the information that I wrote in the form. So, the form part is working fine. What I want is that where I press the submit button, it not only gets the form data but also the data wrote inside of the table. I don't know anything about PHP. My main objective is to store all the data in Firebase but first, I want to test it with console log. When I press submit, it says: "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". I'm trying only to show the first value next to September to test it. If u know how to fix it, it would be really nice.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Heliconia tech</title>
                <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

            <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
                https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

            <script>
            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            var firebaseConfig = {
            };
            // Initialize Firebase
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            firebase.analytics();
            </script>

            <body id="body">
                <div class="container">
                    <form id="clientForm">
                        <label for="name" autofocus>Nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name"><br>

                        <label for="birthDate">Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="birthDate"><br>

                        <label for="baptismDate">Fecha de bautismo:</label>
                        <input type="date" id="baptismDate"><br>

                        <label for="gender">Género:</label>
                        <select id="gender">
                            <option value="man" selected>Hombre</option> 
                            <option value="woman">Mujer</option>
                        </select><br>

                        <label for="group">Grupo:</label>
                        <select id="group">
                            <option value="ungido" selected>Ungido</option> 
                            <option value="anciano">Anciano</option>
                            <option value="siervoMinisterial">Siervo Ministerial</option>
                            <option value="precursorRegular">Precursor regular</option> 
                            <option value="otrasOvejas">Otras ovejas</option>
                        </select><br>
                    <br>
                    <table id="clientTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="tableText">Año de servicio </th>
                            <th class="tableText">Publicaciones</th>
                            <th class="tableText">Presentación<br> de videos</td>
                            <th class="tableText">Horas</th>
                            <th class="tableText">Revisitas</th>
                            <th class="tableText">Cursos<br> bíblicas</th>
                            <th class="tableText">Notas</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Septiembre</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="septemberEntry"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Octubre</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Noviembre</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Diciembre</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Enero</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Febrero</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Marzo</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Abril</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Mayo</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Junio</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Julio</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th contenteditable class="tableText">Agosto</th>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                            <td class="buttonBackground" contenteditable id="input"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><br>
                    <button id="buttonSubmit">Enviar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <script src="js/index.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

And this is the JS Code

```
    var clientForm = document.getElementById('clientForm');
    var clientTable = document.getElementById('clientTable');

    clientForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = clientForm['name'].value;
        var birthDate = clientForm['birthDate'].value;
        var baptismDate = clientForm['baptismDate'].value;
        var gender = clientForm['gender'].value;
        var group = clientForm['group'].value;
        var septemberEntry = clientForm['septemberEntry'].value;


        console.log(name,birthDate,baptismDate,gender,group,septemberEntry)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `clientForm['name']` is undefined.  Turns out, that's now how you reference form fields in JavaScript.

If you want to get a named element from a form, use this instead:

```
clientForm.elements.namedItem('name')
```

Then you can get its value:

```
clientForm.elements.namedItem('name').value
```

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp) for more detail.

Comment: If you're having a new problem with additional code, please post a new question explaining the new problem.

Comment: Thanks Doug for the info, the problem is the same actually, I was showing that it didn't work the solution. Thank you! I'll erase the last comment with code